# Launch chrome Driver on user's computer

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-grid

I'm working on web application for testing website on remote computer using selenium webdriver.
 I have downloaded the Chromedriver.exe to MyDocuments. 
I have set the 'webdriver.chrome.driver' using System.setProperty() and started ChromeDriver(). It works fine.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\MyDocuments\\chromedriver.exe;
driver=new ChromeDriver();
```

My problem now is when a user access on my site, the chrome driver is launched on the remote computer an not in user's computer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be that the user does not have chromedriver.exe downloaded in his `C:\\MyDocuments\\chromedriver.exe` folder. Otherwise the chrome driver has to get opened up in his computer

Comment: chromedriver.exe is installed in C:\\MyDocuments\\chromedriver.exe. When I run my application on remote computer the webriver launch nice. But when I access the url of the remote computer from onother computer the webdriver launch on the remote computer. Is it clear ?

Comment: So, as per my understanding, there are 3 computers, where in chromedriver.exe is in first machine, and you are trying to run your web tests from second computer, it is working fine. But when you try to run the cases from third computer, the browser is getting launched in second computer not in the first one. Is my understanding rite?

Comment: running web tests from second and third computer work but the pop up of chrome browser display on the first computer.PS: chromedriver.exe is in first machine.

Comment: Can you please paste the complete driver initialization code here. So that i can help you

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverpath
     + "\\chromedriver.exe");
   DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
   ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
   options.addArguments("test-type");
   capabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary", "<Path to binary>");
   capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
   driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
driver.get("https://www.google.com");

Comment: can you help me please?@k.s. Karthik

Comment: There is no need to have 5th statement "capabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary", "<Path to binary>"); " as you have set the path of the Chrome browser using System.setProperty. Please remove the line and try to execute the same. This should work. Please let me know if you facing the same issue

Comment: I found that selenium grid is able to run tests on diffrent machines in parallel. But the problem that I must enable Selenium server in every machine(node). Have you any idea about this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110597/discussion-between-k-s-karthik-and-manel-chaabene).